# Error when using pip install django_markdown

Tags: python, django, terminal

I am having the following error when doing `pip install django_markdown`, could someone please explain to me what the issue is?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 283, in run
requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 1435, in install
requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 671, in install
self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 901, in move_wheel_files
pycompile=self.pycompile,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 215, in move_wheel_files
clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 205, in clobber
os.makedirs(destdir)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django_markdown'

Storing debug log for failure in /Users/andrewnguyen/Library/Logs/pip.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is reporting an `OSError` at the bottom of the traceback, explaining that you're having a permissions issue with the file in question.

Try running as root first:

```
sudo pip install django_markdown
```

If that doesn't work, then you could try doing

```
sudo chmod +rwx /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django_markdown
```

though I doubt the latter will fix the problem if the former doesn't.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the help. Totally forgot about using sudo.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have the rights to write to '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/', you can solve installing the package using sudo

```
sudo pip install django_markdown
```

anyway this is not a best practice if you need this package only for a specific application.

Take a look at [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to properly manage python environment.